# How to save a python print out to text when running the python in batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, printing, save

I am currently running a python script in a batch file. In the python, I have some print function to monitor the running code. The printed information then will be shown in the command window. In the meantime, I also want to save all these print-out text to a log-file, so I can track them in the long run.

Currently, to do this, I need to have both print function in the python and use the text.write function to write to a text file. This causes some troubles in maintenance because every time I change some printing text, I also need to change the text in the write function. Also I feel it is not the most efficient way to do that.

For example:

```
start_time = datetime.now()
print("This code is run at " + str(start_time) + "\n")
log_file.write("This code is run at " + str(start_time) + "\n")
```

I would like to use the print function in the python, so I can see that in the command window and then save all the print-out information to a log file at one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a function

```
def print_and_log(text):
    print(text)
    with open("logfile.txt", "a") as logfile:
        logfile.write(text+"\n")
```

Then wherever you need to print, use this function and it will also log.

Answer (score 2):

For a better solution in the long run, consider the built in [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html). You can give multiple destinations, such as stdout and files, log rotation, formatting, and importance levels.

Example:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='log_file', filemode='w', level=logging.DEBUG)

logging.info("This code is run at %", start_time)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I am not familiar with logging package. I have tried the code and it outputs too many info. Since my current project is a small program I am afraid this might be an overkill.